# Windows Installation Folders

Tags: windows, installation

Where do I find a definitive guide as to where, when I am installing a new application into Windows, the application exe's, database tables, configuration files should go?

Also guidelines to which registry keys should be used for persisting user and application data.

Best regards,

Simon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995853.aspx

Comment: For the click-averse: the above link is MSDN's "Application Specification for Microsoft Windows 2000 for Desktop Applications"

Answer (score 3):

Check out Microsoft's suggestions: [Windows File System Namespace Usage Guidelines](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=88AD7E7C-4068-48B8-9503-E160A6693BBA&displaylang=en#filelist) seems to be what you want. (the file name is slightly misleading - the downloadable PDF file shows these guidelines both for Windows Vista and Windows XP)

To find and query those programatically, **see the MSDN [Known Folders topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911(VS.85).aspx)**; also see the [list of common Known Folder constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762584.aspx). Simplest example for [SHGetKnownFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762188(VS.85).aspx) and the Startup folder:

```
SHGetKnownFolderPath(
    FOLDERID_Startup,
    0,
    NULL,
    path_will_be_here_when_function_returns
)
```